# remote::github_install dependency failure

Tags: r, github

install_github broken for dependencies on packages previously installed from private github repo.

When installing from a private repo, fails if the package depends on another package from the private repo--even if its already installed. Example makes this clear

```
install_github('MyAcct/Preinstalled.Package', auth_token = 'x')
# works
install_github('MyAcct/My.Package', auth_token = 'x', upgrade = FALSE)
# Fails if My.Package depends on Preinstalled.Package -- see below
```

I get the following errors.

```
Downloading GitHub repo MyAcct/My.Package@master
Error: HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`MyAcct`) and repo name (`Preinstalled.Package`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

Why is it even checking the repo, since the package is already installed?

This used to work under the old devtools::install_github implementation

Comment: You haven't given us a reproducible example.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue after adding an additional repository to github. It seems that the name of one install_github repository is being cached somewhere, which leads to this error message. Have you managed to solve it?